# Move center of mass of an object to the origin?

Tags: edit-mode, transforms

I have a single mesh that is offset from the center. All I want is to move it to the origin such that the center of mass (the average of all the points) lies at coordinate 0,0,0.

I have tries searching this up and all I get is how to move the cursor to the center of mass, which is not what I want.

Comment: why don't you just move the origin first to the center of the mass and then press alt-g (or ctrl-g or enter 0/0/0 to location)? (object -> set origin -> center of mass)

Comment: You cannot create mesh objects with heterogeneous density in Blender. The center of mass is calculated on the distribution of the geometry in assumption of a homogeneous filled object - so you cannot define the center of mass to any arbitrary point.

Comment: However - it depends on what you want to do. While setting the origin to the _Center of Mass_ always takes the actual geometry into account, when you are using _Rigid Body_ physics the simulation takes the origin (no matter where it is placed) as center of mass into account. This is why sometimes simulations produce unexpected behaviour when people are not aware that their origin is offset from the mesh's actual center of mass.

Comment: But I guess what you want is not creating an own center of mass at the origin but only move the mesh with its center of mass to the world's center. Then @Chris already has the answer for you.